# C++ set using linear probing?

Tags: c++, caching, set, unordered-set

Is there data structure similar to unordered_set that uses linear probing?  Wouldn't such a data structure take advantage of cache hits?  If so, why does unordered_set use linked chaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library associative containers can't invalidate pointers or references to elements (unless they are erased, of course). Thus, linear probing wouldn't provide mich benefit: the elements need to be allocated outside the array to support resizing the array. Once the elements are not part of the array, chaining them seems to provide better control over collisions.

Answer (score 1):

This approach allows references to stored objects remain valid even after rehash and iterators also remain valid after most of operations. On the other side it is expected for hash table to contain a single element matching hash to be effective  - otherwise not so effective linear search will be used anyway.